# Angular Material Table pagination not working, listing all rows even though the paginator is shown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-material-paginator

I am trying to paginate an angular material table. The table at present is having dummy static data , in future once the backend api is ready it will be called to populate the table. At present, the table is not showing the data as paginated. All rows are shown even though the Angular material paginator is shown at the bottom of the table. I tried all the related stack overflow answers but still even though the paginator is displayed the table was displaying the entire data as such. The code below is the same code copied from the angular material example, I have used the same code in a new component with the exception that the column names are different.

*home-component.html*

```
<div class="col-12">
  <table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

*home-component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  styleUrls: ['home-component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'home-component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but couldn't. Can you please take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubqwlt?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: @yurzui It seems to work on the stackblitz, I think there is a difference in the way the stackblitz process the code, even though you didn't have the `implements AfterViewInit` added to the Table example component it seemed to work somehow. I am also confused as to why the code is not working on the local dev server when the same code works on online editors. It seems it has to do with the way the data is loaded, when the paginator is assigned to the datasource in the browser the data seems to be not present, even though it is static. It works if I try to have a input field submission.